# How to upload text file data into sqlserver database using c#?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

my text file like this.

```
name :Settings, id :1, preference :Mail
name:test ,id:2,preference :testMail
```

I need to read that textfile and placed that as records in sqlserver database.

```
name         id   preference
 settings     1      Mail
 test         2      testMail
```

How to parse that textfile like as above .please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Management Studio 'Import Data' task, that generates an SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLbulkcopy method of C#.net to insert textfile data into sql server table.

Check this [**LINK**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57243/Reading-CSV-File-and-Inserting-Data-to-SQL-Table-u)